# Is it ok to use new to create and initialise a page instead of pagefactory.initelements method

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was developing a pagefactory based framework. I had earlier used pagefactory.initements method to inintialise and move from page to page. Init method basically does the same work as saying Homepage HP = new HomePage(driver);

So it is necessary to use init method in pagefactory?
Will we loose something if we do not use it and instead use new to create a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Java PageFactory with annotations yes.

The `PageFactory.initElements(driver, My.class)` command parses the annotations and sets up the Java Proxy classes.  If you don't `.initElements()` none of the WebElements in your class will have locators assigned to them and they will all be null.

You can put the `.initElements()` in your constructor if you just want to new up a page e.g.:

```
public class MyPage {

    public MyPage(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: If Iam not using @findby annotation, then I can skip using .initelements() entirely correct?

Comment: If you aren't using annotations there is no point in using PageFactory at all.